# Nesting HTML in a string with mithril

Tags: html, mithril.js

I would like to generate the following HTML with Mithril's `m`:

`<p>I am a <code>person</code></p>`.

I'm currently using `m.trust` for this:

`m.trust("<p>I am a <code>person</code></p>")`.

But I don't like the HTML string. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use `m` function to do this:

```
m('p', [
    'I am a ',
    m('code', 'person')
])
```

See a whole component here: https://jsfiddle.net/rtkhanas/02adbhkt/

Answer (score 1):

Where the html string come from?

If you are writing your view, then use m('p', ...) instead of `m.trust`
For example, if only the "person" value is dynamic, you should have something like:

```
window.WhoAmI = {}

WhoAmI.controller = function(attr) {
    var ctrl = this

    ctrl.gender = m.prop(attr.gender)
}
WhoAmI.view = function(ctrl) {
    return m('p', [
        'I am a ',
        m('code', 
            ctrl.gender()
        )
    ])
}
```

If you get the whole html string from a request, then it's probably a bad thing, and you should try to rewrite your API (if possible) to send only the dynamic value to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like this:

```
m.module(document.body, {
    view: function() {
    return m('p', [
        'I am a ',
        m('code', 'person')
    ]);
  }
})
```